# Ensuring Alarms Work after App Update

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, updates

My application is almost ready and now one thing which I got to know that after update, all alarms set by user will go off. For that I read a lot and found I have to user package replace in manifest to check update and receive in broadcast. Here is what I added in manifest and tested as it sent broadcast when I change versioncode in gradle.

```
  <receiver
            android:name=".AppUpdateHandler"
            android:exported="false">

            <intent-filter android:priority="900">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
          </receiver>
```

Now next is the code which I used to set alarms,

```
 public void setalarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, AlarmReceiver.receivercode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        userdefinedinterval = sharedPreferences.getString("date", "");
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), Integer.parseInt(userdefinedinterval) * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000, pendingIntent);
                }
```

I read and got to know about pending intent ids, which I my case is AlarmReceiver.receivercode. But now need help to what should I do to keep my app alarms active after update. Do I need to call all alarms via broadcast which is capturing update status or something else is possible. One more thing, I have added boot completed in manifest too so that alarm keep working after reboot. Here I m checking status of each option associated with alarm via sharedpreference and then trigger alarm respectively. Do I need to handle update in same way?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution of it. It can be done in same manner as we do for boot completed. Just call bootcompleted receiver class on update and all alarms will be reset as per user settings.
Or just copy alarm method in update receiver and its is done.